# EncoderCNN Keeps Loading Non stop with [*] on jupyter notebook

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision

Edit:
After further investigation, the issue was moving the encoder to gpu driver
For a reason i don't know, the print statement before encoder.to(driver) doesn't print, it just go directly to move it to cuda,

Now the issue is the below

RuntimeError: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED

Old Issue:-

This code is on udacity, and i should use the GPU as it will be too slow without it,

When i try to run the below code, it gets stuck with [*] sign in the cell, only when GPU is enabled, I tried the code without GPU and it worked perfectly

I added few print functions to know where exactly it stops, it stops exactly while loading the encoder,

when it does that i can't stop it even with Stop button, i have to restart the kernel

this is the model.py

`import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models

class EncoderCNN(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, embed_size):
super(EncoderCNN, self).**init**()
resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
for param in resnet.parameters():
param.requires_grad_(False)

```
    modules = list(resnet.children())[:-1]
    self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*modules)
    self.embed = nn.Linear(resnet.fc.in_features, embed_size)

def forward(self, images):
    features = self.resnet(images)
    features = features.view(features.size(0), -1)
    features = self.embed(features)
    return features
```

`

this is the code iteself

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/cocoapi/PythonAPI')
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
!pip install nltk
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from data_loader import get_loader
from torchvision import transforms
import torch

# Watch for any changes in model.py, and re-load it automatically.
% load_ext autoreload
% autoreload 2

# Import EncoderCNN and DecoderRNN. 
from model import EncoderCNN, DecoderRNN

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Specify the dimensionality of the image embedding.
print('starting')
embed_size = 256

#-#-#-# Do NOT modify the code below this line. #-#-#-#
print('embed done')

# Initialize the encoder. (Optional: Add additional arguments if necessary.)
encoder = EncoderCNN(embed_size)
print('encoder done')

# Move the encoder to GPU if CUDA is available.
encoder.to(device)
print('to device done')

# Move last batch of images (from Step 2) to GPU if CUDA is available.   
images = images.to(device)
print('images device done')

# Pass the images through the encoder.
features = encoder(images)

print('type(features):', type(features))
print('features.shape:', features.shape)

# Check that your encoder satisfies some requirements of the project! :D
assert type(features)==torch.Tensor, "Encoder output needs to be a PyTorch Tensor." 
assert (features.shape[0]==batch_size) & (features.shape[1]==embed_size), "The shape of the encoder output is incorrect."
```

This is the output

starting
embed done
Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet50-19c8e357.pth" to /root/.torch/models/resnet50-19c8e357.pth
100%|██████████| 102502400/102502400 [00:00<00:00, 127632380.11it/s]

i updated the ipykernel, it didn't solve it

!pip install ipykernel --upgrade

i updated the pytorch, it gave me another errors due to version mismatch, so had to reset the project again.

this shouldn't be loading anything, so i guess waiting more time won't solve the issue